# Call base class method when derived class overloads it

Tags: python, class, overloading

I have the following:

```
class A(object):
    def x(self): print "Hello"
    def y(self): self.x()

class Abis(A):
    def x(self): print "Bye"

a = Abis()
a.x()
a.y()
```

Which prints:

```
Bye
Bye
```

But I actually wanted:

```
Bye
Hello
```

Since I want `A.y` to call the "original" `A.x`. How can I reference the original `A.x` in `A`, when the derived class has overloaded it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
class A(object):
    def x(self): print "Hello"
    def y(self): A.x(self)
```

...although that's slightly weird.  Why are you (or, why is someone) overriding `x` if you don't want it called in this situation?

If you don't want it overridden, give it a double-underscore prefix:

```
class A(object):
    def __x(self): print "Hello"
    def y(self): self.__x()
```

Anyone defining `__x` in a derived class will get their own unique `__x` that doesn't override yours - see [Private Variables and Class-local References](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

Comment: Difficult to explain: Abis.x is actually calling A.y which is calling A.x. Abis.x is extending A.x functionality, in a transparent way, but must make ultimately use of A.x.

Comment: If it is "difficult to explain" and an outside observer says it is "slightly wierd", you should probably consider whether your design could be improved.

Answer (score 5):

You want the "super" function:

```
super(Abis, self).x ()
```

This will call "x" on the base class.  See: docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Comment: This would mean the base class definition of `A` would have to know that the sub-class `Abis` was the one being used. The correct answer is that if you want it to call `A.x` then call `A.x(self)`